# In Haskell, could `a` be anything?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-constraints, parametric-polymorphism

While I have been reading the documentation I always thought that `a` could be anything in:

```
example :: a -> a
```

'a' could be a `Char`, `String`, `Int`, `Integer`.

Of course if I put:

```
example :: [a] -> a
```

The imput should be a list, but a list of whatever: `["ab", "cd"]`, `[1,2]` or `['s', 'c']`.

But in my code:

```
toString' :: (Show a) => [a] -> String
toString' [] = "empty"
toString' [x] = " and " ++ show x
toString' (x:y:[]) = show x ++ toString' [y]
toString' (x:xs) = show x ++ ", " ++ toString' xs
```

It should work, but isn't always working:

```
Prelude> toString' ['a', 'b', 'c']  -- Works
Prelude> toString' [1, 2, 3]  -- Don't work
Prelude> toString' ["abc", "bc", "efc"] -- Don't work
```

I don't understand why I need to add the `Show` constraint if normally in the examples of the book I don't need it.

UPDATE

Ok, no, it isn't the change from `["abc", "bc", "efc]` to `["abc", "bc", "efc"]`, actually in the code I have it right, it's only here that I typed it wrong, first.

And about the `Show`, can you answer me if it's necessary to use it in this code?

UPDATE 2

I don't know if this going to be usefull if you downvoted it, or it will be closed, but anyway

The code works better if in the last line I use:

```
toString' (x:xs) = show x ++ ", " ++ (toString' xs)
```

but still don't understand why I need the `Show` (I mean, why I can't remove it from the code?)

UPDATE 3

I see my error with `Show`, if you use a variable type `a` and not a `String`, you need `Show`, maybe because it could Haskell doesn't know which type it is until you put a value, so it needs to know you'll want to show it, or because there are some types of variables that don't extend `Show` by themselves.

Comment: The last is because you forgot to close a string literal.

Comment: And the second one actually works for me.

Comment: "I don't either understand why I need to put the 'show' if normally in the examples of the book It don't need it." - This should probably be a separate question, and you should elaborate on it, e.g. by showing one of the examples where you don't need it.

Comment: Voting to close, questions whose answer turns out to be "this is a typo" are off topic on SO.

Comment: @Cubic the OP claims they made the copying error when typing the question on SO, not in the actual code. Without the `"` we get a different error than the one shown in the Q. So it's unclear. But they also asked about the necessity of  `Show` context.

Comment: @ooootramas yes, it is either `toString' :: [Int] -> String` (or similar), or `toString' :: (Show a) => [a] -> String`. the last one means it should work for *any* type `a`, as I write in my answer. (this is how you can *ping* a user on SO in the comments: type @ and then Tab to complete the name, then type your message to them; they will be notified).

Comment: don't worry about the votes. you have two up votes, it's OK.

Comment: ok, Thank you @WillNess  ;)

Comment: you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just copied your code into my GHCi and all three of your examples work. `Prelude> toString' ["abc", "bc", "efc"]` produces 
`"\"abc\", \"bc\" and \"efc\""`.

What I think happened is you tried your definition inside GHCi without the type signature, and monomorphism restriction kicked in. That's why only one of the examples "worked" for you.

About the `Show` constraint, since you're using  `show :: Show a => a -> String` function, yes, it is necessary.

If you were defining a *specific* version `toString'Int :: [Int] -> String` (or `Char`) there'd be no problem. But you're defining it for `[a]` -- for *any* `a`. And since you're using `show (x :: a)`, *any* `a` that this function accepts must belong to `Show`. This is expressed as `(Show a) => ....`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a type error, this is a *syntax* error. You're just missing the closing quote on the end of the line.

```
toString' ["abc", "bc", "efc"]
                            ^
```